# Create TypeFaceSpan from TypeFace below SDK version 28

Tags: android, textview, android-typeface, android-spannable

I found a way to `create` `TypeFaceSpan` from `TypeFace` like this :

```
fun getTypeFaceSpan(typeFace:TypeFace) = TypeFaceSpan(typeFace)
```

**But** this API is **allowed** only in **API level >= 28** . Any **Compat** libray to achieve this **below 28**?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

`TypeFaceSpan` **is a** `MetricAffectingSpan`. So even if there is **not any exact way** to **get** `TypeFaceSpan` from `Span`, we can make `CustomTypeFaceSpan` like below and use it in place of `TypeFaceSpan`.

```
class CustomTypefaceSpan(private val typeface: Typeface?) : MetricAffectingSpan() {
    override fun updateDrawState(paint: TextPaint) {
        paint.typeface = typeface
    }

    override fun updateMeasureState(paint: TextPaint) {
        paint.typeface = typeface
    }
}
```

And Use it like this :

```
val typeFaceSpan = CustomTypefaceSpan(typeface)
```

Answer (score 1):

Inspired on the answer from @erluxman and combining with Kotlin's extension functions:

```
fun Typeface.getTypefaceSpan(): MetricAffectingSpan {
    return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) typefaceSpanCompatV28(this) else CustomTypefaceSpan(this)
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
private fun typefaceSpanCompatV28(typeface: Typeface) =
    TypefaceSpan(typeface)


private class CustomTypefaceSpan(private val typeface: Typeface?) : MetricAffectingSpan() {
    override fun updateDrawState(paint: TextPaint) {
        paint.typeface = typeface
    }

    override fun updateMeasureState(paint: TextPaint) {
        paint.typeface = typeface
    }
}
```

then you can use it like this:

```
typeface.getTypefaceSpan()
```